# JS / Jquery .load and .length

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I'm new to Jquery/javascript with almost all of my experience being in PHP. I am now finding the importance of how things are ordered :)

So I'm trying to load some `<div>`s into the container `#text-container` using `.load` and then count them. My understanding of jquery's `load` function is that the 2nd argument is a callback function which will only run once all data has been loaded. But it is always reported as 0 even if there are 4-5 divs being placed in the container. Am I missing something?
1.txt

```
<div>1</div><div>2</div>
```

Code:

```
$("#text-container").load("1.txt",alert($("#text-container div").length));
```

This is just an example but I need to use that number to do a whole bunch of maths in other functions. So if I call those instead of alert and try to run .length in there they all get 0 and my math doesn't work :(

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

```
$("#text-container").load('1.txt',function(){
    alert($("#text-container div").length);
});
```

**Explaination**

First let us talk about the callback function passing, the right syntax:

```
$(selector).load(source,callback);
```

Suppose you have some function named as `gg` and we want to use it in place of callback

```
function gg(){
    //some code for task 1
}
```

now lets use it as callback

(**the wrong way**)

```
$(selector).load(source,gg());
```

*Note: when you write the function with parenthesis `()`, the function is called at the same time, so you just need to pass the **identifier***

(**the right way**)

```
$(selector).load(source,gg);
```

**OR USE ANONYMOUS FUNCTION**

```
$(selector).load(source,function(){
    // some code for task 1
});
```

*Note: Instead of defining a function only for callback and if you are not using it again it is preferred to use anonymous function*

Answer (score 2):

You need an anonymous function for the callback

```
$("#text-container").load("1.txt", function(data) {
    alert( $("#text-container div").length )
});
```

> This is just an example but I need to use that number to do a whole
>   bunch of maths in other functions.

Note that it's async, so you can't use it until it's actually there, and why would your `.txt` file contain DIV elements, seems like the wrong file extension to me ?

Comment: Thanks for this. THe data being held is for a very specific layout scenario hence why they are stored in TXT files. Each txt file has about 200-500 DIVs and we have 1,000,000+ txt files

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing what you think you do. You pass the **result** of alert() as an argument.

`$("#text-container").load("1.txt",alert($("#text-container div").length));`

is equivalent to :

```
var data = alert($("#text-container div").length); // data = 0
$("#text-container").load("1.txt", data);
```

**What you want is to pass a function as an argument :**

```
var callback = function() {
  alert($("#text-container div").length);
}
$("#text-container").load("1.txt", callback);
```

or shorter :

```
$("#text-container").load("1.txt", function() {
  alert($("#text-container div").length);
}
```